# Why is a profile mandatory for acquiring archetypes in non-Central repositories?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I use Maven 3.2.1 and maven-archetype-plugin 3.0.1 on Windows 10.

I deployed archetype to my repository and defined it in `settings.xml`, but archetype could not be found.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>archetype</id>
    <url>https://mydomain/repos</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

The execution result is as follows.

```
DOS> mvn archetype:generate \
     -DarchetypeGroupId=my.sample \
     -DarchetypeArtifactId=some-archetype \
     -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=sample \
     -DartifactId=sampleartifact -Dversion=1.0.0

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (my.sample:some-archetype:1.0.0) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (my.sample:some-archetype:1.0.0)
```

However, specifying profile works fine.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>myprofile</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>archetype</id>
        <url>https://mydomain/repos</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This works as expected only by adding "-P myprofile".

```
DOS> mvn archetype:generate \
     ...
     -P myprofile
```

I always want to prioritize my repository, but do I have to specify a profile each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected, a profile is for a specific situation, it is for settings that are sometimes appropriate.  It is entirely reasonable to expect the selection of a profile or to define a default profile.

The simplest way is to make a specific profile active using the global or your personal setting.xml file to add the following.

```
<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>profile-name</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Alternatively you can mark any profile active by default

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
  <profile>
<profiles>
```

Alternatively you can mark a specific profile as active.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>env</name>
        <value>dev</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it almost. As you say, I think that profile exists for certain circumstances. However, according to the DTD in settings.xml, <repositories> can also be written directly under <settings>. I thought that it would always be effective, but I was wrong. Why is it that there is no effect unless <repositories> is set to profile? I will mark "Solved" later.